# using 'with respect to'

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I want to write an email to my consultant saying that "**attached files are the details with respect to our meeting and RFI's raised by contractor**"

Is this correct way to use "with respect to"???

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Please share what research you have already done, and what you found that confused you.  There should be some examples of "with respect to" online -- what do you think the answer might be?  (To improve your question, use the **[Edit]** button on your question and add details, please.)  Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct way to use "with respect to"???

Yes.

The definition of this phrase is "concerning or in relation to something".
"Respect" here means "reference" or "relation".

You are using an abbreviated style of speech that appears in certain circumstances such as the subject line of emails or headlines. A full sentence would be:

> The attached files contain all the details with respect to our meeting and the RFI's raised by the contractor.

It's your decision if you'd prefer to use the abbreviated style or not.